# Prove that there exists no scalar field which has derivative $> 0$ at a fixed point wrt every direction

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, scalar-fields

The problem statement : Prove that there is no scalar field $f$ such that $\nabla_\vec{y}f(\vec{a})>0$ for a fixed vector $\vec{a}$ and every non-zero vector $\vec{y}$. 
Here $\nabla_\vec{y}f(\vec{a})$ represents the derivative of $f$ at $\vec{a}$ with respect to  $\vec{y}$.
$$ \nabla_\vec{y}f(\vec{a})=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(\vec{a}+h\vec{y})-f(\vec{a})}{h}$$
I proved it using that if $\vec{y}\neq0$ then $$\nabla_\vec{-y}f(\vec{a})=-\nabla_\vec{y}f(\vec{a})<0$$
This gives a contradiction. Is there any other way to prove this ?

Comment: Yep I know that, but is there a different approach other than this ?

Comment: The directional derivative is the dot product of the gradient vector and the unit vector in a particular direction. This gives that if reverse the direction of the unit vector directional derivative changes its sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that every proof you find is going to be equivalent to the one you already gave, but here is a proof by meme.  If such a function existed, it would be possible to walk from one point on the graph to another, uphill both ways.

[image: meme describing a path from home to school. The path goes over a giant hill, labeled with “snow” on top. But slopes of the hill are labeled with “uphill.”]

Comment: could use a few arrows (or stick figures or something) to indicate the direction the guy's walking on both sides of the hill...

Answer (score 1):

Note that the directional derivative is the inner product of the gradient vector at a given point and the unit vector in some given direction. Now, if we replace our unit vector with the negative of the vector, the directional derivative changes its sign, and it is due to the definition of the inner product.

Comment: The definition in the body of the question is the **definition** - the fact that the directional derivative is that dot product is a theorem! The OP's proof looks perfectly correct to me (he doesn't show how he got $D_{-v}=-D_v$, but that's trivial from the **definition**).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  My bad. I have never seen the formula in this format.  Now I see that since $f$ is a scalar-valued function, it should be correct and should make sense. I am very sorry.  Thanks so much for raising the issue.

Comment: It makes sense if $f$ is vector-valued as well Whatever - don't miss the "Edit" link...

Comment: Thank you again.

Comment: Why not simply _delete_ the parts that you want to take back. I don't see the point to keeping the problematic statements there and then saying "that was wrong" at the bottom.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you very much, Professor.

Comment: I should just drop this. But I can't help it: What problem do you see with that definition if $f$ is vector-valued?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, my initial understanding is not correct. In fact, now I don't have any issue if $f$ is vector valued. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call $\nabla^{\vec{a}} f : \vec{y} \rightarrow \nabla_{\vec{y}} f (\vec{a})$.

$\nabla^{\vec{a}}$ is a linear application, which can only be either identically zero (which is forbidden by hypothesis) or take both positive and negative values.

(Of course this ends up being much the same as your proof, especially if you want to give explicit illustration of the statement)